# How to send formatted message to Slack from google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api

I am sending messages from Google Sheets to Slack via Slack API. I can format them with markdown, but possibilities are limited.

I am trying to send messages formated with [Slack Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/) to send nicer messages, but I am not able to send them formatted. When is message received in Slack, it only shows JSON in plain text.

Code, that I am using to send from sheets to slack is:

```
var POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";

function postLoop () {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input")
 var rangeValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (i=1;i<rangeValues.length;i++){
    var channel = ''+rangeValues[i];
    postToSlack(channel)
  }
}

function postToSlack(channel) {
  var message = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Message").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var payload = {
    'channel' : channel,
    'text' : message,
    'as_user' : true
  }
  
return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT,
  {
    method             : 'post',
    contentType        : 'application/json',
    headers            : {
      Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'MyTokenID'
    },
    payload            : JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
})
}
```

I have tried different ways of putting example json code generated from [Slack Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/), but result was always same, just received plain text message.

Example code I tested on:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Problem is probably somewhere in parsing and sending json to slack, but my understanding of it is minimal. Can you please help me to find correct way how to send it formatted?